# Calculating average time differences between rows on the same table

Tags: mysql, select

The table sca_ticket_thread stores status change dates.  I am attempting to calculate the average time difference between two statuses.  The "created" column stores the date of the status change and the "body" column stores the status change.

```
SELECT AVG(DateDiff((SELECT created FROM 
(SELECT created 
FROM sca_ticket_thread 
WHERE body = 'AchangetoB'
OR body = 'BchangetoC'
GROUP BY ticket_id
HAVING count(*) > 1)
as subquery),
(SELECT created 
FROM sca_ticket_thread 
WHERE body = 'BchangetoC' 
ORDER BY ticket_id))) 
FROM sca_ticket_thread
```

The error I receive is:  #1242 - Subquery returns more than 1 row

I (conceptually, a little bit) understand that a subquery cannot return more than 1 row.  I've looked into joining a table to itself as a possible solution, but I don't think that is the right path forward.

Ultimately, I would like to generate average status changes from A to B, B to C to D, etc.

```
ID | STATUS   | DATE
--------------------------
1  | Status A | 02/01/2015
1  | Status A | 02/02/2015
2  | Status B | 02/03/2015
```

Comment: Run the two subqueries and see what they return. I can't recall any restriction on how many rows the subquery can return. For example: `SELECT * FROM X WHERE x_id IN (SELECT x_id FROM X where x_value LIKE 'foo%');` is perfectly valid and the subquery can return multiple rows. Some options to achieve what you want include: `LIMIT`, `GROUP` with `MAX`/`MIN`, etc.

Comment: The first select statement returns 24 rows and the second 17.  Is that the problem?

Comment: Yes. DateDiff expects only two arguments. You need to filter out the other rows to get the one that you want. Also you should probably make sure that multiple 'AchangetoB' and 'BchangetoC' is valid, if it's not you can probably tighten the schema to prevent that.

Comment: Thanks for the help so far @nevets1219, but I am struggling to filter the select statement.  To strip down my problem, picture a table with three columns:  ID, Status, Date and three rows:  1, Status A, 2/1/2015  |   1, Status A, 2/2/2015  |  2, Status B, 2/3/2015.  I am trying to write a select statement like this:  [\SELECT Status FROM Table WHERE Status = A but only if the associated ID also has a row with Status = B

Comment: I don't think  you are describing your relationships clearly enough or maybe I'm not seeing it. I've edited in the example you gave but I'm not seeing how anyone can tell A has gone to B or that it should go to B. This is part of your business logic that the database doesn't and shouldn't care about. It might make more sense if your schema was: `ID, start_status, end_status, date`. Then you would have: `[{1, \0, A, 02/01/2015}, {2, A, A, 02/02/2015}, {3, A, B, 02/03/2015}]`

Comment: Furthermore, it feels like this table can only track the status of ONE thing. But I'm guessing you simply care about the latest date and only care about two given statuses. So you can try something like: `SELECT MAX(sca_ticket_thread.created) FROM sca_ticket_thread WHERE body = 'AchangetoB'` for your subquery.

Comment: I figured it out (see below), but once I plug it into the original script I'm hit, once again, with the #1242 - Subquery returns more than 1 row.  Unfortunately, I am attempting to pull this data from an open source ticketing system so the db structure is outside of my control.  I'm just a beginner, but the structure you outlined in your comments makes a lot more sense then the baked-in sca_ticket_thread table......SELECT created FROM 

(SELECT ticket_id, created, body 
FROM sca_ticket_thread 
WHERE body = 'AchangetoB'
OR body = 'BchangetoC'
GROUP BY 1
HAVING count(*) > 1)
as subquery

Comment: OK, the comments section is probably getting too chatty. In the future just edit and append to your question.

Comment: If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1. Also, note that dates in SQL adhere to a specific format.

Answer (score 0):

Let's take a look at your latest query:

```
SELECT AVG(DateDiff(
  (SELECT created FROM (
    SELECT ticket_id, created, body
    FROM sca_ticket_thread
    WHERE body = 'AchangetoB' OR body = 'BchangetoC'
    GROUP BY 1
    HAVING count(*) > 1) as subquery),
  (SELECT created FROM sca_ticket_thread WHERE body = 'BchangetoC' ORDER BY ticket_id))) 
FROM sca_ticket_thread
```

A couple of problems stand out:

1. Your subquery is returning multiple columns (ticket_id, created, and body) but you don't actually use them so you should just retrieve `created`. Not an actual problem but it does impact performance so you should keep that in mind.
2. I didn't know about `GROUP BY 1` but it is valid (learn something new everyday). In this case it basically means `GROUP BY ticket_id` (the first column in your `SELECT`). I don't think this is valid as you are selecting out 3 columns but you are only grouping by 1 column.
3. I think you are trying to limit the response to just one row with the `HAVING` but in this case it means return results that give me results whose ticket_id appears more than once.

My MySQL is a bit rusty but I think that's right.

I think I was confused but what you probably need to do is not use subqueries but use grouping and/or joining. Perhaps you can post a brief example using the schema you presented in your query. Something like http://sqlfiddle.com/ would be pretty handy for people looking at the question and for your own debugging.

There are several other answers that might be helpful:

- [Avg Time difference in mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1231122/avg-time-difference-in-mysql)
- [MySQL AVG(TIMESTAMPDIFF) with GROUP BY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7269949/mysql-avgtimestampdiff-with-group-by?rq=1)